# Combining lists with python using two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
f= ['A', 'A']  
d = [(2096, 222, 2640), (1494, 479, 1285)]
```

I want a list!

```
LL = [('A', 2096, 222, 2640), ('A', 1494, 479, 1285)]
```

I am close with 
dic = zip(f,d)

but this give me this:

```
[('A', (2096, 222, 2640)), ('A', (1494, 479, 1285))]
```

How can i get LL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
LL = [ (x,) + y for x, y in zip(f, d) ]
```

This iterates through the convoluted arrays and adds the string outside the tuple to the tuple (by creating a new tuple, due to the fact tuples are immutable).

Comment: Note that it does not really *add* to the tuple, as tuples are immutable. It creates a new tuple.

Answer (score 1):

the zip command does that along with dict:

```
>>>dict(zip([1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
{1:1,2:2,3:3}
```

Comment: @user428862: Then why did you tag the question with `dictionary`? ;) (and you name the variable `dic` btw which suggest to hold a dictionary, but this is me being nitpicking...)

Comment: I realized that dictionary refers to something I thought I wanted/needed. but its a list. "a: 34, 56, b: 565, 67"  is not what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `map()` instead of `zip()`

```
LL = map(lambda x,y:(x,)+y, f, d)
```

`(x,)` is equivalent to `tuple(x)`

```
LL = map(lambda x,y:tuple(x)+y, f, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[(x,) + y for x,y in zip(f, d)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have a list of strings and a list of tuples. Tuples are immutable, so you will have to reconstruct each tuple.

For only 2 items you can try:

```
[tuple(f[0])+d[0], tuple(f[1])+d[1]]
```

For N number of items look for "list comprehension", for example here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html or build them up using a loop if that is more understandable.